# Neurobiology of tantrums

Tags: human-biology, brain

As mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantrum), tantrums are primarily observed in young children and often involve a loss of self-control, both physical control and the ability to calm after a demand has been met. What changes in neurobiology reduce the propensity for this as children age? (The cause may be partly neurochemical, partly structural.)

I am especially interested in whether the vulnerability to tantrums in the young brain are at least partly due to positive feedbacks. A self-enhancing mechanism for the distress could explain why self-control sometimes suffers. (Positive feedback is also consistent with a colleague's claim, for which I have no source, that the risk of loss of self-control is low if a demand is met quickly.)